# How do I avoid undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when trying to change form inpu to json data?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, forms

Short Version: I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

and the error highlights this code as the problem code:

```
def sizes
    read_attribute(:sizes).map { |s| Size.new(s)  }
  end
```

Why and how do I stop that from happening?

Longer Version: (I based using the json column on this [post](http://faxon.org/2015/02/03/edit-rails-activerecord-json-attributes-in-html-forms))

The thing I'm not sure I'm accounting for in my attempt is that in this article they're describing how to do all of this using Postgres and I'm using MySQL.

I'm trying to take data from a form and split two of the pieces into a JSON format on one column. Here is the relevant portion of my schema:

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description", limit: 65535
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.json     "sizes"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id", using: :btree
  end
```

The JSON column will have `amount`(read sizes) and a `cost` associated to it. This is all about pizza and the many different sizes and associated prices based on size. Entering the data should look like this, I'm ignoring the category_id for now.

```
Product.create(name: "Neapolitan", sizes: { "small":9.95, "medium":10.95, "large":11.95, "xlarge":13.50, "xxlarge":29.95})
```

The above code works just I expect it to when I use `rails console`. The problem has something to do with my model and view/form. Basically, I keep asking myself, "why is 'nil' a problem here, nothing is set yet, that's the point of a form? Everything should be 'nil' "

Here is my Product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  VARIANTS = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'xlarge', 'xxlarge'].freeze

  def sizes
    read_attribute(:sizes).map { |s| Size.new(s)  }
  end

  def sizes_attributes=(attributes)
    sizes = []
    attributes.each do |index, attrs|
    next if '1' == attrs.delete("_destroy")
    sizes << attrs
    end
      write_attributes(:sizes, sizes)
  end

  def build_size
    s = self.sizes.dup
    s << Size.new({amount: '', cost: 0})
    self.sizes = s
  end

  class Size
    attr_accessor :amount, :cost

    def initialize(hash)
      @amount     =hash[:amount]
      @cost       =hash[:cost]
    end

    def persisted?() false; end
    def new_record?() false; end
    def mark_for_destruction?() false; end
    def _destroy() false; end

  end

end
```

`amount` acts as the key and the `cost` acts as the value. `VARIANTS` is where I'll pull my selection of locked in sizes.

Here are my forms:
_form.rb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :category_id %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%# f.collection_select :sizes, Product::VARIANTS, :to_s, :to_s %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :sizes %>
      <%= f.fields_for :sizes do |size_form| %>
        <%= render "size_fields", f: size_form %>
      <% end %>

    </div>


    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_size_fields.rb

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :amount %>
  <%= f.collection_select :amount, Product::VARIANTS, :to_s, :to_s %>
  <%= f.label :cost %>
  <%= f.text_field :cost %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", "#", class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

products_controller.rb

```
# GET /products/new
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @categories = Category.all
  @product.build_size
end
...
# POST /products
# POST /products.json
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @categories = Category.all


  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
...
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :category_id, sizes_attributes: [:amount, :cost, :_destroy] )
  end
```

What am I getting wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: well, the attribute is `nil`, that's why you get the error, try changing the line: `read_attribute(:sizes).map { |s| Size.new(s) }` to `(read_attribute(:sizes) || {}).map { |s| Size.new(s) }`, that way if `nil` is returned by `read_attribute(:sizes)` then you just return an empty hash. I don't know if that's going to work for for what you're trying to do but it will certainly get rid of the error you're getting.

Comment: @fanta I tried something similar earlier in trying to deal with this problem and I also tried what you suggested now, but I still get the same error.

Comment: What versions of Rails and MySQL are you using? Also, what part of your code is triggering the error (aka where are you calling `.sizes`)?

Comment: @muistooshort `sizes: { {""small:19.25}, {"medium":23.55} }` a hash of hashes I suppose. Right now I'm not that picky, I'm trying to figure out how to add into a JSON column through a form and then I was going to tackle the best way to structure that data to get the output I want. I just need `Product` to hold data for each pizza/food style and have the `sizes` column hold a `size/amount` that corresponds to a specific `cost`. I don't currently have a strong reason to hold a preference. I'm already weary of potential problems, but if you have suggestions, I'm open to change.

Comment: @mmichael `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper` Well `better_errors`  says this code: `def sizes
    read_attribute(:sizes).map { |s| Size.new(s) }
  end` which is in the product model. But other possible offenders are `@product.build_size` in the controller which calls `build_size` in product model.  This is build_size: `def build_size
    s = self.sizes.dup
    s << Size.new({amount: '', cost: 0})
    self.sizes = s
  end`

Comment: btw, this `{ {"small":19.25}, {"medium":23.55} }` is not a valid hash, a hash hash keys and values, you would need something like `{ "small":{"small":19.25}, "medium": {"medium":23.55} }` or `{ "small":19.25, "medium":23.55}`.

Comment: @fanta So what is the best way to say something like:  `product.find(2).sizes("small")` and have the `cost` returned without telling me small again.  In the example you put, I'd ask for the small cost of a product and it would return {"small":19.25} and I'd have to pull out the value from it. Is there a better way to do this? It seems strange that small would be returned as part of the answer to the question "what is the cost associated with small?" clearly I've misunderstood how to use the hash efficiently.

Comment: @Lenocam Looks like you're overriding some of the getter/setter methods in your `Product` model, so those could be causing conflicts with your form. Try commenting those out and try to pass `{ "small": 19.25, "medium": 23.55 }` for `sizes`.

Comment: if what you want to do is something like `product.find(2).sizes("small")`, then you don't need to override `sizes` in your model, why ?, you already have a hash like `{ "small": 19.25, "medium": 23.55}` in your database, so, doing `product.find(2).sizes["small"]` or `product.find(2).sizes[:small]` (try with both) would do the job. Notice that I'm using `[]` and not `()`